# VCO - sawtooth and duty cycle?

Tags: oscillator, vco

I've successfully built a VCO using an LM13700 OTA. The circuit generates square and triangle wave. I wonder if I can add a couple of diodes and a potentiometer to be able to skew between triangle-ramp/saw and change the duty cycle of the square wave? Is it that simple?

[image: LM13700 OTA VCO]

The second schematics gives you an idea of what I meant. It's a similar circuit realised with op amps.
[image: op amp oscillator]

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled "LM13700 VCO" and the top answer was the pdf file which contained: -

[image]

Figure 37 should help and figure 38 is for a sinewave. Note that if this is to be part of a synthesizer project you'll need octave / volt tuning and not linear tuning as per your design and TI/Nat semi design.